# Erro ao fazer update em tabela no MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados

Bem gente, eu tenho o erro abaixo, ao tentar fazer o update em uma tabela no MySQL e não entendo o porque, estou a buscar correctamente os dados no formulário, mas mesmo assim, não me deixa fazer o update, o que faço?

```php
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bd_calcadocharme");

$codigo_user=$_POST['codigocli'];
$nome=$_POST['nome'];
$tele=$_POST['telemovel'];
$data_nasc=$_POST ['Data'];
$sexo=$_POST['sexo'];

$Rua=$_POST ['rua'];
$pais=$_POST ['escolher'];
$cidade=$_POST ['cidade'];

$user=$_POST ['user'];
$password=$_POST ['pass'];

echo 'Código do Cliente: '.$codigo_user.'</br>';
echo 'Nome do Cliente: '.$nome.'</br>';
echo 'Nº de Telefone:  '.$tele.'<br>';  
echo 'Data de nascimento: '.$data_nasc.'</br>';
echo 'Sexo: '.$sexo.'<br>'; 
echo 'Rua: '.$Rua.'<br>';   
echo 'País: '.$pais.'</br>';    
echo 'Cidade: '.$cidade.'</br>';    
echo 'Username: '.$user.'<br>';
echo 'Password: '.$password.'<br>';

    $sql="UPDATE clientes SET nome='$nome' , morada='$Rua', datanasc='$data_nasc',  sexo='$sexo', pais='$pais', cidade='$cidade', telemovel='$tele','user='$user', senha='$password' WHERE user='$user'";);
    echo "<p></p>";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        echo "Dados alterados com sucesso!";
    } else {
        echo "Erro ao tentar alterar dados na base de dados!";
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

?>
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''user='raquel', senha='123' WHERE user='raquel'' at line 1

Consulta gerada:

> Erro ao tentar alterar dados na base de dados!ERROR: Could not able to
>   execute UPDATE clientes SET nome='odacil' , morada='doscolhoes',
>   datanasc='1993-10-07', sexo='FEM', pais='pt', cidade='feijo',
>   telemovel='966622665','user='raquel', senha='123' WHERE user='raquel'.

Answer (score 4):

No update tem um aspa simples sobrando, causando o erro:

```
 'user='$user'
 ^--- aspa a mais.
```

Basta remover ela ou pode se livrar de todas elas utilizando prepared statements como abaixo:

```
$sql = "UPDATE clientes SET 
       nome = ?,
       morada = ?,
       datanasc = ?,
       sexo = ?,
       pais = ?,
       cidade = ?,
       telemovel = ?,
       user = ?,
       senha = ?
    WHERE user = ?";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssssssss', $nome, $Rua, $data_nasc, $sexo, $pais, $cidade, $tele, $user, $password, $user);

if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    echo "Dados alterados com sucesso!";
}else{
   echo "Erro ao tentar alterar dados na base de dados!";
   echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Os vários `s` em [bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) definem o tipo de dado, os disponíveis são:

```
s - string
i - integer
d - double
b - blob
```